# How to get result based on 2 query in CI

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

sorry for the confusing title as I really did not know what to type. I'm new to CI and now I'm trying to convert my code to CI and stuck here.

here is my original code:

```
$query_domain = $konek->prepare("SELECT * FROM `domain` WHERE `id` = :id");
$query_domain->bindParam(":id", $id);
$query_domain->execute();
$data_domain = $query_domain->fetch();

$query_owner = $konek->query("SELECT * FROM `people` WHERE `id` = $data_domain->ownerid");
$data_owner = $query_owner->fetch();
```

So basically it request a domain where the domain id is X
and then it request data of the owner based on an owner id that is in domain table.

I'm not really sure what to put in **controller or model**
but here is my current model:

```
    public function get_domain($id){
    $this->db->get_where('domain', array('id' => $id));
}

public function get_domain_owner($ownerid){
    $this->db->get_where('client', array('id' => $ownerid));
}
```

Comment: Why not using sql join to get the data_owner using a single db query ?

Answer (score 0):

In your (Client) model:

```php
public function get_owner_with_domain($domain)
{
  $query = $this->db->select('c.*')->
  from('client c')->
  join('domain d', 'd.ownerid = c.id')->
  where('d.name',$domain)->get();

  if ($query) {
    return $query->row_array();
    // Or, ideally return a client if you have a Client model
    // return $query->row(0,'Client'); 
  } else {
    // log error?
    return false;
  }
}
```

In your controller:

```php
public function client($domain) // or whatever your function might be called
{
  $this->load->model('Client'); 
  $client = $this->Client->get_owner_with_domain($domain)
  // Do something with the client
  // var_dump($client);
  $view_data['client'] = $client;
  $this->load->view('client_info',$view_data);
}
```

Further reading:

[CodeIgniter ActiveRecord reference](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

[CodeIgniter Results reference](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply by using a single query

```
SELECT people.* FROM people, domain WHERE people.id = domain.ownerId AND domain.id = :id
```